# Can't read file in visual c

Tags: c, visual-studio, file

I need to read some strings from a file and then sort them.
Here's the file section of my code (functions and other tasks are working fine):

```
#define FILENAME "E:\\Projects\\Es9Funz\\Words.txt"

int main() {
    char string[MAX], word[MAX], sortedWord[MAX];
    FILE* fp;
if ((fp = fopen("FILENAME", "r")) == NULL); {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", FILENAME);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

if (fscanf(fp, "%s", word) == EOF) {
    fprintf(stderr, "File %s empty\n", FILENAME);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

do {
    //some tasks
} while (fscanf(fp, "%s", word) != EOF);

fclose(fp);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

so my output is:
Can't open E:\Projects\Es9Funz\Parole.txt

but that's the same folder where my main is

Thanks for your help

Comment: `"FILENAME"` -> `FILENAME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code block:

```
if ((fp = fopen("FILENAME", "r")) == NULL); {
fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", FILENAME);
return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

Instead of "FILENAME" (Which is just a char*)

You should insert FILENAME as the constant defined (Use it as a variable)

Comment: The output is "Can't open E:\Projects\Es9Funz\Words.txt"

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? it seems like it should work.
try seperate the file opening from the if statement. 
please update me.

Comment: `fp = fopen (FILENAME,  "r");`    then `if (fp == NULL); {`   but it's still not working. I even tried with the file in another location but nothing

Comment: You do not put `;` after an `if` statement, just open brackets.

Comment: This should fix your problem. (my last comment)
Please update,
Omer

Comment: Thank you so much, that  ;  was the problem. Again, thanks